# Jquery Code to show link while checkbox is checked on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a following piece of code which works fine, when i check or uncheck the checkbox, but when i initially loads my page and some of my checkboxes are already checked, i want to show the div box to be visible but the code is not doing so, am i missing anything

please guide through the following code

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //check the state of the checkox
    $(".showinvoice").is(':checked') {
        var stats = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#"+stats).css('display','block');
    }
    //check the code only when the click button is triggered    
    $(".showinvoice").click(function(e) {
        var getStudent = $(this).attr('data-id');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#"+getStudent).css('display','block');
        } else {
            $("#"+getStudent).css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if condition is missing : if($(".showinvoice").is(':checked')) {

Comment: probably want an each there as well.  i forget how is() works truthy if there are multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're missing the `if` statement around the `.showinvoice` state condition.

Secondly you should use the `data()` method to access `data-*` attributes. You should also use the `change` method when dealing with radio and checkbox inputs so that the events are still raised by users who navigate using the keyboard. Lastly you can remove the `if` statement and just use `toggle()` instead.

To achieve what you require all you need to do is raise a `change` event on the checkboxes on load of the page. Try this;

```
// check the state of the checkox
if ($(".showinvoice").is(':checked')) {
    var stats = $(this).data('id');
    $("#" + stats).show();
}

// check the code only when the click button is triggered    
$(".showinvoice").change(function(e) {
    var getStudent = $(this).data('id');
    $("#" + getStudent).toggle(this.checked);
}).change(); // < to run this code when the page loads
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first part to...

```
//check the state of the checkox
$(".showinvoice:checked").each(function() {
    var stats = $(this).data('id');
    $("#"+stats).css('display','block');
});
```